# Delete data from the list of tables used in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I have around 100's of databases. In each of database a SP Proc1 is used which deletes data from number of tables performing some other operations as well. 
I am working on another procedure which is generic for all these database where I too need to delete data from tables.
e.g. The below sp deletes T1 and T2 tables from DB!, but for DB@ it may delete from T1 and T3

```
USE DB1
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE PROC1
AS 
BEGIN
...
DELETE FROM T1
DELETE FROM T2
...
END
```

I am working on the procedure which will be generic for all databases and will delete from the same list of tables (T1 and T2 if db is DB1, T1 and T3 if db is DB2)

I hope this explains my problem to answer them. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic SQL.

eg:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(100)
select @sql = 'delete from ' + @tableName
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Although I wouldn't necessarily advise this genericised approach without reservations.

Comment: This is subject to sql injection

Comment: @Madhivanan Yes, depending on where `@tablename` comes from. I'm not suggesting it should be passed as a parameter from the user.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PROC1
AS 
BEGIN
...
DELETE FROM DB1..T1
DELETE FROM DB1..T2
DELETE FROM DB2..T1
DELETE FROM DB2..T3
...
END
```